# valgrind conditional jump or move error

Tags: c

i have searched throughout the forum and i saw that many encounter the same issue, but i can't solve it.
I keep getting the : "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)"error on the follow code :

```
void printStack(stack S)
{
    node current;
    current = (node)S->last;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        S->labelFunc(current->value);
        current = current->prev;
    }
    //free(current);
}
```

the printStack function is getting a stack and prints the Elements of the stack (because the stack is an ADT) which are char*s.
for some odd reason i keep getting the error on the while line, i tried mallocing a place for the current node, i tried initialising the prev and next pointers of it, i tried checking if the stack i got is null, but all of that was in vain...

the labelFunc is just a printing function, which prints each char*.

thanks

Comment: You shouldn't have a need to cast `S->last` to `node`. In any case, `node` seems to a `typedef`ed pointer type, usually in the context of C this is frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that `S->last` (or one of the `node->prev` pointers) has not been initialised.

Comment: thank you very much i found the error, indeed, i didn't initialised something down the road :P

Comment: I don't know because you show just part of your code, but I suggest u to use `calloc` instead `malloc` if u have to allocate memory for array of also for a struct with array inside (in case you can't allocate them statically). In general this prevent conditional jump caused by memory not initialized by `malloc`.